# should state be stored before login in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, callback

login_required can be used as decorator in django, but a login.html with user/password is restricted by app.

```
@login_required
def myview(request):
...
```

now i want to display a button in login.html to redirect user to other site's oauth flow. 
the site fix my callback url static. And user/password are not needed now.

so how to redirect user to last request(maybe post with data), after callback from oauth server?

should session/cookies be used to store request object?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach session information to an anonymous user's session in Django; everybody gets a session cookie, anonymous or not. That data is kept after the user logs in.

If your session data is stored in the database, though, then it will take up more and more space over time, and you will want to have a periodic task that clears out the old sessions.

But should you be saving POST data for later replay?

In certain cases, this may be okay -- when you know for certain that the POST request is idempotent, has already been run once, and that the data is just being used to generate the correct page for the user to see.

You probably shouldn't implement this as a generic solution, though. If a GET request can be constructed that redirects through OAuth and then automatically POSTs as the authenticated user, then you likely have a major CSRF hole on your hands.